# Can´t write to topic with remote producer in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, producer-consumer, apache-kafka-security

So I´m trying ot write to a topic in my cluster with a producer that´s on a seperate device than the broker and zookeeper servers. I´m using SSL_SASL authentication and I believe that there is an issue with the authentication but I dont get any log messages regarding this so I could be wrong. When I run this command:

> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list raspberrypi:9092 --topic my-topic --producer.config config/producer.properties

I get this repeating crash:

> [2023-04-19 12:55:38,819] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (raspberrypi/192.168.1.104:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
> [2023-04-19 12:55:38,819] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker raspberrypi:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

But when I try to do the same command on the same machine as the broker it works just fine.

## Here is my configuration

server.properties

```
broker.id=0
confluent.http.server.listeners=

listeners=SASL_SSL://raspberrypi:9092,SASL_SSL1://192.168.1.104:9093

advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://raspberrypi:9092,SASL_SSL1://192.168.1.104:9093



listener.security.protocol.map=SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,SASL_SSL1:SASL_SSL

zookeeper.connect=raspberrypi:2182


log.dirs=/tmp/data/broker-0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

# Properties for SSL Zookeeper Security between Zookeeper and Broker

zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
zookeeper.ssl.client.enable=true
zookeeper.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location=/home/pi/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/ssl/kafka.broker.truststore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password=exjobb123
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location=/home/pi/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/ssl/kafka.broker.keystore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password=exjobb123

zookeeper.set.acl=true

# Properties for SSL Kafka Security between Broker and its clients

ssl.truststore.location=/home/pi/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/ssl/kafka.broker.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=exjobb123
ssl.keystore.location=/home/pi/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/ssl/kafka.broker.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=exjobb123
ssl.key.password=exjobb123
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
#Properties for SASL between a broker and its client

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-512
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-512.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="kafka-admin" password="exjobb123";
listener.name.sasl_ssl1.scram-sha-512.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="kafka-admin" password="exjobb123";
super.users=User:kafka-admin

#Properties for Authorization
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
```

producer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=raspberrypi:9092
compression.type=none
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
ssl.truststore.location=/home/exjobb/ssl/kafka.producer.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=exjobb123
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="sasl-producer" password="exjobb123";
```

I tried to allow the ports 9092 and 9093 on the firewall to no avail, as I said I also tried running the producer on the same machine as the broker and then it worked fine. The logs for the broker and zookeeper doesnt say anything aswell.

Any help is much appricieted and let me know if you want any additional information that I might of missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means to only accept requests from hostname `raspberrypi` on port 9092, which explains why it worked locally.

```
listeners=...://raspberrypi:9092
```

If you'd used `192.168.1.104:9093` as your broker list instead, it may have worked.

You don't need both hostname and IP listed in listeners and/or advertised.listeners, but listeners is a bind address. Change it to `0.0.0.0:<port>` to accept all external connections.

Beyond that, it's unclear how you've allowed `sasl-producer` user to access the cluster. You'll need to run `kafka-acls` commands, I believe.

Sidenote: Redpanda would be less resource intensive on a Raspberry pi, while still maintaining Kafka compatibility. You also don't technically require Zookeeper anymore.

+ Never store important data under /tmp

Comment: I did use the kafka-acls command to give it access to the 'my-topic' topic, and the remote machine has the raspberrypi domain in its /etc/hosts file. Thank you for the recomendation of Redpanda I´ll have to give that a try, and I´ll try chaning listerners to 0.0.0.0:9092

Comment: Changing raspberrypi:9092 to 0.0.0.0:9092 in listeners solved it! Thank you for you help and kind repsonse (I´m very new to Kafka).

Comment: Do not edit hosts files. https://confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/